# Why 'No signing identity found' error now?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I don't have a paid developer account. Using XCode I used to be able to test iPhone apps on my iPhone. But now it won't run and instead gives me the error 'No signing identity found' and I'm ushered off to pay £79 for the developer program.

Why would this have stopped working?

I"m using XCode 6.1.1 and have an iPhone 4.

Answer (score 1):

Without the paid developer account you won't be able to test on a device. As to why you were able to before and unable to now I have no idea.